# Filter a list of objects in Liquid

Tags: liquid

I have a list of objects like this:

```
{
    "devices": [
        {
            "model": "foo",
            "serial": 123
        },
        {
            "model": "foo",
            "serial": 456
        },
        {
            "model": "foo",
            "serial": 123
        },
        {
            "model": "foo",
            "serial": 678
        },
        {
            "model": "bar",
            "serial": 321
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to get the count of unique devices of model 'foo'.  But there can be duplicate devices (i.e., the serial #).  I So I need to first filter to get the unique devices and then I think I could do this:
`uniqueDevices | where 'model', 'foo' | size`

But the `uniq` operator just works on individual fields in an array.  Not sure how I an have it work on an object and just look at 1 field in the object.

The result I want in this case is 3, since there are 3 unique devices of model='foo'